# Postgresql create a log schema

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, audit, audit-logging

So my problem is simple. I have a schema `prod` with many tables, and another one `log` with the exact same tables and structure (primary keys change that's it).
When I do `UPDATE` or `DELETE` in the schema `prod`, I want to record old data in the `log` schema.

I have the following function called after a update or delete:

```
CREATE FUNCTION prod.log_data() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    v RECORD;
    column_names text;
    value_names text;
BEGIN

    -- get column names of current table and store the list in a text var
    column_names = '';
    value_names = '';
    FOR v IN SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME) AND table_schema = quote_ident(TG_TABLE_SCHEMA) LOOP
        column_names = column_names || ',' || v.column_name;
        value_names = value_names || ',$1.' || v.column_name;
    END LOOP;

    -- remove first char ','
    column_names = substring( column_names FROM 2);
    value_names = substring( value_names FROM 2);

    -- execute the insert into log schema
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO log.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' ( ' || column_names || ' ) VALUES ( ' || value_names || ' )' USING OLD;

    RETURN NULL; -- no need to return, it is executed after update
END;$$;
```

The annoying part is that I have to get column names from `information_schema` for each row.
I would rather use this:

```
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO log.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' SELECT ' || OLD;
```

But some values can be `NULL` so this will execute:

> INSERT INTO log.user SELECT 2,,,"2015-10-28 13:52:44.785947"
>   instead of 
>   INSERT INTO log.user SELECT 2,NULL,NULL,"2015-10-28 13:52:44.785947"

Any idea to convert `",,"` to `",NULL,"`?

Thanks

-Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I must say that in my opinion using PostgreSQL system tables (like `information_schema`) is the proper way for such a usecase. Especially that you must write it once: you create the function `prod.log_data()` and your done. Moreover it may be dangerous to use `OLD` in that context (just like `*`) as always because of not specified elements order.

**But**,

to answer your exact question the only way I know is to do some operations on `OLD`. Just observe that you cast `OLD` to `text` by doing concatenation `... ' SELECT ' || OLD`. The default casting create that ugly double-commas. So, next you can play with that text. In the end I propose:

```
DECLARE
     tmp TEXT
...
BEGIN
...
     /*to make OLD -> text like (2,,3,4,,)*/
     SELECT '' || OLD INTO tmp; /*step 1*/

     /*take care of commas at the begining and end: '(,' ',)'*/
     tmp := replace(replace(tmp, '(,', '(NULL,'), ',)', ',NULL)'); /*step 2*/

     /* replace rest of commas to commas with NULL between them */
     SELECT array_to_string(string_to_array(tmp, ',', ''), ',', 'NULL') INTO tmp; /*step 3*/

     /* Now we can do EXECUTE*/
     EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO log.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' SELECT ' || tmp;
```

Of course you can do steps 1-3 in one big step

```
SELECT array_to_string(string_to_array(replace(replace('' || NEW, '(,', '(NULL,'), ',)', ',NULL)'), ',', ''), ',', 'NULL') INTO tmp;
```

In my opinion this approach isn't any better from using `information_schema`, but it's your call.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! Thanks for your opinion, I will make some tests on big DB to see if `information_schema` is too slow for my usecase.

Comment: In fact this is for performance. But could you tell me when postgres fire triggers? I wonder if postgre gives the return to php before firing a trigger `after INSERT`

Comment: I not 100% sure but I doubt it is. Every trigger (no matter `AFTER` or `BEFORE`) in PostgreSQL is executed in the same trasaction as master query. That means that execution isn't over till trigger ends. Be aware that unhandled exception in `AFTER` trigger makes whole transaction to rollback. So it could makes problems if php would think that query was successful if even db server itself hasn't new that yet.